# How to display data from an api call that returns an object instead of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion.json

This is the api im attempting to work with. For some reason when i go to map over it to pull data from it and display the data it says champions.map is not a function. (I am guessing it says this because i cant iterate over an object using .map. So i tried using Object.keys(champions) and i still cant really get it to do what i want it to do.

I feel im missing something super easy as its been quite some time since i have made any api calls.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ChampionContainer from "./ChampionContainer";
// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const ChampionList = () => {
    const [ champions, setChampions ] = useState([])
    console.log("This is our state",champions)

    useEffect(() => {
            const url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion.json";
            axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                setChampions(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("server Error", error)
            })
    }, [champions]);




    return (
        // Object.keys(a).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
        //     // use keyName to get current key's name
        //     // and a[keyName] to get its value
        //   })
        <div>
            {Object.keys(champions).map((key) => {
                return (<div key={key}>{champions[key]}</div>)
            })}
            {/* {champions.map((champion) => (
                <ChampionContainer key={champion.id} champion={champion}/>
            ))} */}
        </div>

    );
}


export default ChampionList;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you're first attempt at doing `.map()` on `champions` wont work as it is not an array, it's an object.

You're second attempt is closer, though when you do -

`champions[key]`

this returns one of your `champion` objects.  You just need to access the property you want from that object, e.g.

`champions[key].name` - to get the name of the `champion` e.g. `Aatrox`

Comment: Dude thank you so much.. i knew it was something simple.

Comment: No problem, as mentioned in another answer, you should remove `champions` from the dependency array, and just leave the dependency array empty.  `champions` is not a dependency in your case

Answer (score 0):

You have a infinite loop there.
In useEffect pass champions as a parameter, when it changes you excecute useEffect, but in there you setChampions, then champions changes an useEffect is running again. infinite loop as a result.

You debug your program to make sure that respomse.data.data have the information you need?

In setChampions function is better to use setChampions(current => current + newData);
this is an object, so you should use spread operator to map onto a new object.